# Can't set SUPER key to open launcher [Kubuntu KDE Plasma 5]

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys

My let's say Windows key does nothing when I press it. Trying to assign it to display the launcher does not work as it is telling me that I can't use it alone. I have to assign **SUPER + [another key]**.

This is so since the installation of Kubuntu, it never worked.

**How can I tell the system to use it as it is in default in ubuntu?**

What has been tested so far (even if it was stupid to test):

- Works well on my dual-booted Ubuntu
- 'Win' key is recognized by the system as Super
- Super key is recognized when pressed
- Tried with CompizConfig but no show-dash option/plugin
- Tried with ksuperkey without success as I can't assign ALT+F1 till F4 (included), and my 'k' key then opens the launcher...

Thank you in advance for your feedback!

Best,
Edouard

Comment: Quick feedback on this: I did not manage to resolve the problem and will not be able to test solutions, I now changed for another distro where the SUPER key works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If someday you decide to come back to Kubuntu , just try [Ksuperkey](https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey)
Simply run `make` and execute the resulted binary.All done !
It works well for me.
It maps the `Super` key to `Alt+F1` when you "press and release" it , but the `Super` key still can be used in cooperation with other keys while you're just pressing and holding it.